# How to inject List of bean properties by spring SpEL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a properties file for defining dynamic endpoints (name, host and port).

So I created a bean named `EndPoint` with name, host and port as member variables.

How to inject server's host and port dynamically by using Spring `@Value` and SpEL?

**endpoint.properties**

```
names=server1,server2,server3

endpoint.server1.host=192.168.1.101
endpoint.server1.port=10101
endpoint.server2.host=192.168.1.102
endpoint.server2.port=10102
endpoint.server3.host=192.168.1.103
endpoint.server3.port=10103
```

**EndPoint.java**

```
public class EndPoint {

    /** name */
    private String name;

    // hardcode server1 here
    // how to inject server's host dynamically by name?
    // @Value("${endpoint.#{this.name}.host}")
    @Value("${endpoint.server1.host}")            
    private String host;

    @Value("${endpoint.server1.port}")
    private int port;

    public EndPoint(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**EndPointBeanConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource( //
    value = { "classpath:conf/endpoint.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true//
)
public class EndPointBeanConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "endPoints")
    public List<EndPoint> endPoints() {
        final List<EndPoint> endPoints = new ArrayList<EndPoint>();
        final String[] names = env.getProperty("names").split(",");
        for (final String name : names) {
            final EndPoint endPoint = endPoint(name);
            endPoints.add(endPoint);
        }
        return endPoints;
    }

    @Bean(name = "endPoint")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public EndPoint endPoint(String name) {
        return new EndPoint(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving suggestion, Go with YAML/Properties  for this type of implementation in your project.

[This link helpful for your requirement](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/)